# How to send multiple email in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send email to multiple user on single request. I have one member table which contain employee id but that member table do not have email column. Employee table have email column. So when I send request and select member, all selected member should get email.

```
def issue_tracker_group_email(issue_request)
  @issue_request = issue_request
  @issue_request = IssueRequest.find(issue_request.id)
  @issue_tracker_group = IssueTrackerGroup.find(issue_request.issue_tracker_group_id)
  mail(to: @issue_tracker_group.email, subject: 'Issue Request')
end
```

Comment: email goes on only one email id . Above is my code but in that i used issue_tracker_group at place of that table i have to use another table named as issue_tracker_member which don't have email column

Comment: @AnubhiGolechha could you please post IssueTrackerGroup model here?

seems like there are couple things going on here

Comment: has_many :issue_tracker_members,
 has_many :issue_masters,
 has_many :issue_tracker_groups,
 has_many :issue_root_causes

Comment: for sending multiple mails, you have to call your mailer method inside a loop which takes different email ids and pass it to the mailer method

Comment: can u please modify my code and send .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
    def issue_tracker_group_email(issue_request)
      @issue_request = issue_request
      @issue_request = IssueRequest.find(issue_request.id)
      @issue_tracker_group = IssueTrackerGroup.find(issue_request.issue_tracker_group_id)
      @email=@issue_tracker_group.map{|i| i.email}.join(",")
      mail(to:@email, subject: 'Issue Request')
    end
```